# No node.js packages are recognized, despite having Path set right and being installed globally. NPM doesn't give any errors however

Tags: node.js, npm

Solutions I've tried:

- Moved NPM to the first part of user's %PATH%
- Moved NPM to the first part of systemwide %PATH%
- 'npm uninstall  -g; npm install  -g;'
- Reinstalling Node
- Fresh install of Win10
- Set Powershell Execution Policy to AllSigned, then to Unrestricted

The exact error message:

```
gulp: The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gulp
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gulp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I'm actually not sure what information we need here, ask me anything.

Comment: Have you run `npm install -g gulp`?

Comment: Yeah, one of the first things I did. 
Unless order counts? I did npm install gulp -g

Comment: Can you check that your glogal npm dir `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm` and nodejs dir `C:\Program Files\nodejs` is included in path - simply run `$Env:Path` from powershell.

Comment: Yeah, both of those are. 
the more I tinker with this, the weirder it gets. 
I ought to delete this question I think, but I still haven't resolved it, just mutated it. 
I've installed Bootstrap, and that one still doesn't work with the same issue, but Gulp _kinda_ does but throws a different error now. 
Should I update this question, or start a new one, or just try somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe there is not much that we (stack overflow) can do to help. If you are able to create a complete minimal example it might enable us to help you better (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - I understand that it might not be easy in this case. The last suggestion I have left is to try installing `gulp-cli` as well.